# The program perform a loop to sum up all the value in the input. How can I optimize the loop part in MIPS?

Tags: assembly, mips, micro-optimization

```
input:  .word 71 22 13 64 55 46 98

main:   

        addi $t0, $zero, 7   # line 1
        addi $t1, $zero, 0   # line 2
        addi $t7, $zero, 0   # line 3

Loop:   

    sll  $t2, $t1, 2     # line 4     t2 = 0
    addi $t1, $t1, 1     # line 5   t1 = 1
    la   $t6, input      # line 6    t6 = address of 71
    add  $t2, $t2, $t6   # line 7   t2 = address of 71
    lw   $t3, 0($t2)     # line 8    t3 = 71
    add  $t7, $t7, $t3   # line 9       t7 = 71
    bne  $t0, $t1, Loop  # line 10
```

Comment: Lift `la   $t6, input` out of the loop, and increment it by 4 at the end of each iteration rather than calculating the address based on an index for every iteration.

Answer (score 1):

You have:

```
int N = 7;
int i = 0;
int sum = 0;
do {
    int t0 = i << 2;      // scaling i*4
    i++;
    int p = (int) input;  // declaring p as int so addition won't scale as scaling has already been done via i*4
    p += t0;
    int t3 = * (int *) p; // cast to pointer type for dereference
    sum += t3;
} while ( i != N );
```

---

So, Michael's suggestions are to

1. move constants out of the loop — `p = input` is a constant computation, always making the same result, so no need to do that repeatedly, just do it once before the loop.
2. transform from array indexing to pointer dereferencing

Pointers combine the notion of a base address plus an index into one value.  Thus, we can eliminate the indexing variable, `i`.

```
int *p = input;
int *q = p + 7;           // where to stop is &input[7] note that this means p + 7*4 in assembly.
int sum = 0;
do {
    int t3 = *p;
    p++;                  // note that since p is int pointer, ++ in C here means +=4 in asm
    sum += t3;
} while ( p != q );
```

---

You can see that there is less code in general, and much less inside the loop (which is executed once for each element of the array).